# (boost:: && std::) bind fails only on MSVC with too few arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, wt

### Edit: Minimized Code Example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <Wt/WServer>

Wt::WApplication *createApplication(const Wt::WEnvironment& env, int i) {
    return new Wt::WApplication(env);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Wt::WRun(argc, argv,boost::bind(&createApplication, _1, 1));
}
```

> Error 94  error C2198: 'Wt::WApplication *(__cdecl *)(const Wt::WEnvironment &,int)' : too few arguments for call \wt-3.3.4-msvs2013-windows-x86-sdk\include\boost\function\function_template.hpp 95  1

Also fails with `Wt::WRun(argc, argv,std::bind(&createApplication, std::placeholders::_1, 1));` with exact the same error.

---

### Old example

I'm using the library [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/) which has the function `Wt::WRun()` that takes as the 3rd argument a function, in this case `application_creator`,  that returns a pointer to a Wt type and takes one argument. So far so good. This function is user supplied and likely to need more arguments, which I do and also a [example](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/src/wt-homepage) of the lib shows (see main.c, `Wt::WSever::addEntryPoint` takes the same argument as `WRun`).

So I want to bind my additional parameters like in the example. My solution compiles perfectly with gcc/mingw but with MSVC/Visual Studio 2013 Express, it fails with the error

> Error 94  error C2198: 'Wt::WApplication *(__cdecl *)(const Wt::WEnvironment &,int)' : too few arguments for call ...include\boost\function\function_template.h

My call: `Wt::WRun(argc, argv,boost::bind(MDDB_Service::application_creator, _1, 5));`

Definition of the callback `Wt::WApplication* MDDB_Service::application_creator(const Wt::WEnvironment& env, int foo);`

Definition of `WT::WRun`:

```
#define WTCONNECTOR_API __declspec(dllimport)
typedef boost::function<WApplication* (const WEnvironment&)> ApplicationCreator;
int WTCONNECTOR_API WRun(int argc, char** argv,
            ApplicationCreator createApplication = 0);
```

Also the same with `Wt::WRun(argc, argv,std::bind(MDDB_Service::application_creator, std::placeholders::_1, 5));`

> Error 94  error C2198: 'Wt::WApplication *(__cdecl *)(const Wt::WEnvironment &,int)' : too few arguments for call ... include\boost\function\function_template.hpp

Comment: what is the signature of `MDDB_Service::application_creator` ?

Comment: Sorry forgotten, I added it by editing. Thx!

Comment: What is *"Visual Studio 2013 Essentials"*?

Comment: I'm sorry should be namend "express"

Comment: is `application_creator` a member function?

Comment: No it's only a namespace.

Comment: Can you provide a minimized example? I suspect that this shouldn't need wt to reproduce the error.

Comment: Now I was able to minimize the problem

Answer (score 2):

The problem is actually not the fault of the compiler, but rather this line:

```
Wt::WEnvironment we();
```

It declares a function called `we` taking no arguments and returning a `Wt::WEnvironment`. Your are being a victim of [the most vexing parse](http://madebyevan.com/obscure-cpp-features/).
Replacing the line with

```
Wt::WEnvironment we;
```

should fix your problem.

Comment: *Facepalm* I changed the line to `Wt::WEnvironment we;` but it didn't solve the problem, but it seems it reveals the real thing: The default constructor of Wt::WEnvironment is protected, so I guess that restricted construction scenario prevents any usefull binding, e.g. even if the function I bind to can access the constructor, because any conversion is made impossible?!

Comment: @Superlokkus According to what you say, it does indeed fix your problem, but does reveal another one. You can still do the binding, you just have to figure out a way to get a valid `Wt::WEnvironment` instance.

Comment: Indeed if you say that's the reason why the bind fails, it fixes that part of my problem and I use that as leverage towards the Wt library developers, since they encourage this use case.